# how to calulate no of days between start and end date

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to calculate difference between two dates removing holidays including Saturdays and Sundays using dojo(java script library) .can any one guide me giving reference or how to proceed

Answer (score 3):

A quick look at the [Dojo date documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/date.html#usage) shows this possible way:

```
var date1 = new Date(2000, 2, 1);
var date2 = new Date(2000, 2, 5);
dojo.date.difference(date1, date2, "day")
```

For the weekday situation you can just use 'weekday' instead of 'day' in the difference function.  I'm not too sure about holidays but due to their dependance on country then I wouldn't expect them to be automatic depending on your locale/country.

I would recommend look at the date range and defining which dates are holidays for your range, given that holidays can change depending on the year too. There have been other implementations similar to this as a [US Federal holiday day checker in Javascript](http://www.softcomplex.com/forum/viewthread_2814/).

I don't have first hand experience with Dojo, but it might be possible to expand the .difference function and add your own custom routine for 'workingday' or similar.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this method, because it depends of what hour you are in the current day.
For example :

```
var date1 = new Date(2000, 2, 1);
var date2 = new Date(2000, 2, 5);
dojo.date.difference(date1, date2, "day")
```

will returns "5" if it's 8 a.m. and will returns "4" if it's 8 p.m. because it's "rounded to the nearest integer" (according to http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.7/dojo.date.difference )